# How to resolve git push issue ? it stucks at 1 %

Tags: git, github

whenever try to 'git push' it stucks at 1%. e.g.

```
$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': XXXXX
Enumerating objects: 20124, done.
Counting objects: 100% (20124/20124), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (15252/15252), done.
Writing objects:   1% (252/20097), 498.77 MiB | 14.70 MiB/s
```

I have already tried below solutions on the internet

> 1. git config --global core.askpass "git-gui--askpass"
> 2. rm -f .git/index.lock
> 3. git config http.postBuffer 524288000

is it for only internet speed or I am missing something here?

Comment: How big are the objects you're pushing here? It looks like you've pushed 498 MiB in 252 objects?

Comment: some of are zip or rar files. so cant I push it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're pushing a lot of files which do not compress well.

Git stores objects with the Deflate algorithm, which is the same algorithm used in zip files. This generally works very well for text files, which have a lot of redundancy, but works poorly for files which are random or already compressed (in fact, it expands such files).

Git additionally normally deltifies objects before uploading them, and if multiple objects have redundant data, only one copy of that data is stored, and all other copies are replaced with references to that data. The fact that your data is already compressed likely prevents the deltification from being effective as well.

Your output shows that you've uploaded 252 objects and 498.77 MiB has been sent, and that you're uploading at 14.70 MiB/s. The percentage reflects the number of objects that are being uploaded, not the size. This is a respectable upload speed, but your upload will be slower because none of the files compress or deltify well. You're therefore sending much more data than if you had a text-only repository with an equivalent uncompressed size.

If you want to upload archives, you'd be better off uploading uncompressed tar files (or zip files which use the store-only mode), which Git will be able to compress much better, and you'll be able to take advantage of Git's deltification and compression abilities. In general, though, Git is generally not the right tool to store archives or other archival assets, so you may want to look into Git LFS or another solution altogether (such as Bintray or Artifactory), depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

You should also know that GitHub rejects pushes that are larger than 2 GB, and any objects which may be larger than 100 MB. For these large objects, you'll need to use Git LFS, and for large pushes, you'll need to push a few commits at a time.